# Ubuntu 15.10 The installation or removal of a software package failed

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I'm using ubuntu 15.10 and when I try to install application from software center after installation I got this error.when I click Ok I can see that application on my pc but I can't open it.Help me

```
installArchives() failed: Selecting previously unselected package libkeybinder-3.0-0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 231567 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libkeybinder-3.0-0_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkeybinder-3.0-0:amd64 (0.3.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libopencore-amrnb0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libopencore-amrnb0_0.1.3-2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libopencore-amrnb0:amd64 (0.1.3-2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libopencore-amrwb0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libopencore-amrwb0_0.1.3-2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libopencore-amrwb0:amd64 (0.1.3-2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-keybinder-3.0.
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-keybinder-3.0_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 (0.3.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr_1.6.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr:amd64 (1.6.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsidplay1v5.
Preparing to unpack .../libsidplay1v5_1.36.59-8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsidplay1v5 (1.36.59-8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly_1.6.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 (1.6.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package kazam.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/kazam_1.4.5-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking kazam (1.4.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.2~bzr0+15.10.20150627.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Job is already running: runsvdir
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libkeybinder-3.0-0:amd64 (0.3.0-1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Setting up libopencore-amrnb0:amd64 (0.1.3-2.1) ...
Setting up libopencore-amrwb0:amd64 (0.1.3-2.1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 (0.3.0-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr:amd64 (1.6.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsidplay1v5 (1.36.59-8) ...
Setting up gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 (1.6.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up kazam (1.4.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: Try http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Comment: There is already a running `runsvdir`. The interesting thing, `runit` should start the process after installation. Try to stop the process, run `ps -ef | grep runsvdir` to get more information. After that start the installation again.